# Check (in twig template), if Shopware 6 customer belongs to a specific customer group

Tags: twig, shopware, shopware6

I know this Shopware 6 twig condition:

```
{% if context.customer is defined %}
    do show 
{% endif %}
```

But how to check, if a customer belongs to a specific customer group?

Answer (score 1):

You cannot verify directly that the customer belongs to a specific customer group.

For that, you can add [plugin configuration](https://developer.shopware.com/docs/guides/plugins/plugins/plugin-fundamentals/add-plugin-configuration) with the `component` field

```
<component name="sw-entity-single-select">
    <name>customerGroup</name>
    <entity>customer_group</entity>
    <label>Choose a customer group</label>
</component>
```

then you can access it in twig files like,

```
{% set specificCustomerGroupId = config('yourPluginName.config.customerGroup') %}

{% if context.customer.groupId == specificCustomerGroupId %}
    do show 
{% endif %}
```

Answer (score 0):

You might look at the `SalesChannelContext` class or `dump` out the context in your template to see what's available.

You have `currentCustomerGroup` available in the context.

```
{% if context.currentCustomerGroup.id == 'cfbd5018d38d41d8adca10d94fc8bdd6' %}
    do show 
{% endif %}
```

Comment: Maybe this answer could be improved by explaining where to find/look for the group id